# Replace NaN with null when using CreateDataFrame with pandas data

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a csv, converting it to a Spark dataframe and then doing some aggregations. The original csv has missing data, which is represented as `NaN` when read via Pandas. After converting to PySpark, the `NaN` values remain instead of being replaced by `null`. This leads to my `.avg()` aggregation having `NaN` values.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col = False)

spark_schema = StructType([
    StructField("id",StringType(),True),
    StructField("segment", StringType(), True),
    StructField("score",DoubleType(),True),
    StructField("sales", IntegerType(), True)
  ])

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=df,schema=spark_schema).cache()

segment_avg = (
    spark_df
    .groupBy('segment')
    .agg(
        sf.avg('score').alias('score')
    )
)

+----------+------+
|segment   |score |
+----------+------+
|Gold      |NaN   |
|Platinum  |NaN   |
|Silver    |NaN   |
+----------+------+
```

I have tried to replace all `NaN` in `spark_df` like so:

```
spark_df = spark_df.replace(float('nan'), None)
```

But it errors:

> ValueError: If to_replace is not a dict, value should be a float, int, long, string, list, or tuple. Got <class 'NoneType'>

```
spark_df.select('score').show(10,False)

+-----+
|score|
+-----+
|75.0 |
|34.0 |
|NaN  |
|NaN  |
|NaN  |
|76.0 |
|65.0 |
|43.0 |
|78.0 |
|88.0 |
+-----+
```

How can I replace these `Nan` values with `null` so they are ignored when aggregating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isnan` function to replace NaN with null in a column

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan, col, when, lit

spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('score', when(isnan(col('score')), lit(None)).otherwise(col('score')))
```

to replace all NaN in the entire dataframe, use `.replace`

```
spark_df = spark_df.replace(float('nan'), None)
```

Comment: Is there a way to target every NaN in the dataframe rather than individual column?